# If I have the Diverse Obedience feat, can I take lower level boons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, boons

If I have the [Diverse Obedience](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/diverse-obedience/) feat I can obtain the deity's boons of any list assumed I have the [Deific Obedience](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/deific-obedience) feat and no levels in the [evangelist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/evangelist/), [exalted](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/exalted/), or [sentinel](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/s-z/sentinel/) prestige classes. But can I obtain lower level boons in one of such lists? For example as a Sarenrae worshipping PC with 16 HD I can obtain the "Fiery Spirit" boon, the "Healing Sunburst" boon or the "Channel Efficiency" boon. But let's suppose I'm not a paladin or a cleric and I already have fire resistance: can I obtain a lower level boon like "Healing Spirit" instead?

Answer (score 2):

## Technically, a lower-tier boon can't be taken instead of a higher-tier boon…

So far as I can tell from [*Inner Sea Gods*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1601255977), a lower-tier boon can't be picked instead of a higher-tier boon. Were such an option available, it would likely need to be mentioned somewhere in the feat [**Diverse Obedience**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/deific-obedience) as a typical creature only acquires a god's boons from one category (exalted, evangelist, or sentinel), and the creature does so in order. Neither the feat Diverse Obedience nor any other mention of boons in *Inner Sea Gods* seems to allow "dumbing down" a boon choice to a lower tier. (Or, for that matter, picking the same lower-tier boon more than once.)

I don't endorse the game design practice, but it seems that this is a case where if the character has the feat Diverse Obedience (and, by extension, the feat [Deific Obedience](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/deific-obedience)) yet the player finds none of the boons that the god makes available at a specific tier acceptable, the player should've picked for the character a different god. That's not to minimize your frustration! (That's also not an attempt to turn you into a player who only makes choices based solely on their mechanical efficacy—Sarenrae might've been the perfect *narrative* god for the character even if she's not the perfect *mechanical* god for the character!) This kind of possibly-negative choice is endemic to *Pathfinder* and its antecedent *Dungeons & Dragons 3.5*. That is, some choices *are* better for some characters than for others, like which god a character should worship so that the character can receive the boons the player wants for the character. The game rewards planning ahead so that a character *isn't* accidentally or organically stuck with only bad or useless choices. Yes, that kind of sucks. (Also see [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20080221174425/http://www.montecook.com/cgi-bin/page.cgi?mc_los_142).)

### …But allowing a such a choice in the sample case isn't unbalanced

I can't imagine a situation wherein this GM would *forbid* a player from picking for his [Sarenrae](https://aonprd.com/DeityDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Sarenrae)-worshiping character a lower-tier boon over a higher-tier one, especially as the character that's receiving that boon is level 14 or 16. Really, the ability to cast once a day even a 3rd-level spell—as many of Sarenrae's lower-tier boons do—is an ability that a player can forget his level 14 character even has.